# Output PHP in a view?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an include that passes vars:

```
@include('site.my-view', ['text' => '<p>some text</p>'])
```

But I wish to put some text and php in the text var, like so:

```
@include('site.my-view', ['text' => '<p>some text {{ $myVar }}</p>'])
```

But this is rendered out as:

```
some text <?php echo $myVar ?>
```

Inside my-view the text var is output like so:

```
{!! $text !!}
```

How can I get it to actually echo? i've tried {{ }} with no luck.

Comment: You'd probably be better off utilising the ComposerServiceProvider for passing variables to numerous pages if the controller doesn't already pass it

Comment: Not possible in my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this -

```
@include('site.my-view', ['text' => '<p>some text '.$myVar.'</p>'])
```